# write to core data file

Tags: core-data, xcode5

I am completely new to xcode and therefore objective-c. Now writing my first app, woo hoo! :-) The app is supposed to be a dictionary. I am having a problem writing to a field in a core data sqlite database. My table is called WordDict and the fields are; aNum (string), bLetter (string), cCategory (string), dWord (string), eEnglish (string) and fFav (BOOL).

I am able to read the data into a pickerView control and display the info that correspond to the row in the pickerView in a textView. However, I would like that once a word and its meaning is in the pickerView and textView respectively, I can click a button, (btnAddToFav) and the BOOL YES would be updated to the fFav field of the present record that is showing in the pickerView.

I tried a few things but don't know how to pass the value of the present field for fFav from the fetchedResultController to the button action to update the field.

I tried a few things that crashed the program a couple times with some error: coredata error (19) primary key must be unique to other wild ones such as: NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 19.

I am at my wits end, not that I had much to begin with :-). Here is some of my code below:

```
#import "SMPWPCDetailsVC.h"

@interface SMPWPCDetailsVC ()
{
    int count;
}
@end

@implementation SMPWPCDetailsVC

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize forFavToUpdate = _forFavToUpdate;
@synthesize forFavWord = _forFavWord;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)letterCheck: (int) numValue{

    if ([self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].count <= numValue) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:_lblCategoryText message:@"The letter chosen does not have entries that fit the above category." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }else{
        WordDict *slang = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:numValue];
        _txtMeaning.text = slang.eEnglish;
        _forFavWord = slang.dWord;
        _forFavToUpdate = slang.fFav;
        count = (int) slang.aNum;
    }
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self letterCheck:0];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _lblLetter.text = _lblLetterText;

    //Passes the managedObjectContext along from the AppDelegate
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController]performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle the error
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"For some reason there was a problem connecting to the database. Please restart the app and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Controls section
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    // Display the Words we've fetched on the picker
    WordDict *slang = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];
    return slang.dWord;

    //Another way to do it -- return [[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"dWord"];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    [self letterCheck:(int)row];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel *tView = (UILabel *)view;
    if (!tView){
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
        tView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
        tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        tView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    // Fill the label text here
    [tView setText:[[[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row]valueForKey:@"dWord"]];
    return tView;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched Results Controller section
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WordDict"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cCategory == %@ AND bLetter == %@",_lblCategoryText,_lblLetterText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dWord"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"bLetter" cacheName:nil];

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}

- (IBAction)btnBack:(UIButton *)sender {
}

- (IBAction)btnHome:(UIButton *)sender {
}

-(void) addToFav: (int) favValue{
    WordDict * addFav = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:favValue];
    addFav.fFav = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnAddToFavs:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self addToFav:count];
}

@end
```

Any ideas??

Thanks for any help you can give.

Regards,
Socaprice

OK I got this to work. I added the code below:

```
-(void) addToFav:favCriteria{
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"WordDict" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aNum == %@",favCriteria];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if([fetchedObjects count] > 0)
    {
        WordDict *slangObj = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        slangObj.fFav = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        // Handle the error
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"For some reason there was a problem connecting to the database. Please restart the app and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnAddToFavs:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self addToFav: _forRecToUpdate];
}
```

And I change a value in the first code section:

```
    _txtMeaning.text = slang.eEnglish;
    _forFavWord = slang.dWord;
    _forFavToUpdate = slang.fFav;
    count = (int) slang.aNum;
```

to:

```
_txtMeaning.text = slang.eEnglish;
_forRecToUpdate = slang.aNum;
```

And that worked cause I first had to get the value of a unique field in the database then find on that criteria. That allowed me to change the value of the field in the database.

Now my only problem is how to refresh the picker control. But that is another question... :-)

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Are you using iCloud? That's the only time I've seen the "primary key must be unique" message.

Comment: No, I am not. I actually created the sqlite database using the core data but then extracted it to populate it by using firefox. Everything was working fine until I decided to write to it. Since I am now learning, I thought it was because I did that extraction and populate process but I don't think so.

Comment: Editing a Core Data file with a general purpose SQLite editor is a good way to get files that Core Data can't read. The internals of how Core Data uses SQLite are not documented.

Comment: True so I will continue to populate it that way. However, there must be a way to get access to the record that is presently showing in the pickerView and make changes to one of its fields.